# Users Authentification with Active Directory in CMS

Tags: wordpress, drupal-7, active-directory, ldap, radius-protocol

I am currently working on a intranet with a CMS (Drupal or Wordpress). I have to authenticate the users via Active Directory Database (more precisely Server Radius). I don't want to import the data but just check if the login and password are correct in AD. I search if there were a module/plugin in Drupal or Wordpress but i'm very lost because i found LDAP plugins and not Server Radius.... 
What's the difference between the two ? and can i use those plugin ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use WordPress and use [Active Directory integration plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/). it is very easy to use and configure and best of all it works.

1. install WAMP and Wordpress. [here is tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/)
2. enable php ldap extension (check the below given instruction).
3. install [Active Directory integration plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/installation/)
4. fill up all required configuration detail. (such as domain controller, Base Dn and       Account Suffix this filed must be filled)
5. test the connection.
6. login to WordPress standard login screen using AD user info.
7. instruction to enable ldap php extension using wamp.

   ```
    *click on wamp icon on task-bar*

    *click on php floder*

    *click on php extension*

    *select php_ldap e.g*
   ```

[image]

let me know if you stuck somewhere or if any of the above instruction don't make sense.

hope that help.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Vijay ! I was confused with this issue and resolve it using ActiveX. I get user's windows login using ActiveX (WScript.Network) and create an account using the unsername on Wp. I choose this solution for this moment because it's an intranet & i had to authenticate users programmaticaly.

Comment: To be more precise, employees don't have to login via the login page because, firsty, they already have a lot of account on other application and we decided to not add another password that they'll never remember and second we thought that the login page will be a brake and they'll never want to visit the intranet. But i'll try your solution and see ! :)